# react navbar button , how to set active

Tags: javascript, html, sass, react-redux

I want my sidebar button to change color when I visit the page it navigates to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and `:active` didn't help that much because it returns to its original css once I click other part in my page.

What you should do is create a class for your selected navbar button

```
.current_active_navbar {
   background-color: $main-red;
}
```

then in your js, create a condition that will apply the `.current_active_navbar` to navbar based on your current URL. You can get your current URL through this `window.location.href`

So let's say your current url is `localhost:3000/timer` then you can have your condition like this

```
if(window.location.href.split("/")[3] === "timer")
```

Comment: sadly if(window.location.href.split("/")[1] === "timer") doesnt do the trick for me

Comment: how did you implement it? how did you use that condition to apply the selected css?

Comment: thats what i did but it doesnt grab the active route

Comment: console.log this first `window.location.href` you might not have a default route

Comment: getBtnClassName() {
    if (window.location.href.split('/')[1] === 'timer') {
      return 'nav_active';
    } else {

      return 'nav__btn';
    }
  }

<LinkButton to="/timer" label="Timer" cssPrefix={this.getBtnClassName()} styles={['block']} />

Comment: oh wait, my bad. Change the index to 3 instead of 1. Let me know if what's the result after

Comment: i fixed that but it makes the button active all the time even if the route changes

Comment: probaly because you have `"timer"` hardcoded in there? try to pass that menu as a parameter like this `cssPrefix={this.getBtnClassName('timer')` then in your function `getBtnClassName(menu) { if (window.location.href.split('/')[1] === menu) { return 'nav_active'; } else { return 'nav__btn'; } }` . Change the parameter based on your route.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too good with CSS myself, but [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp) does a pretty good job of explaining it.